# Showing a linear transformation is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra

I have that D: V $\rightarrow $ V, where it is the transformation that sends the polynomial p(x) = $ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $  over to the polynomial $ Dp(x) = 3ax^2+2bx+c $
I want to show that D: V $\rightarrow $ V is nilpotent. Can I really just do it by recognizing that Dp = p', and then differentiate p(x) enough times?

p(x) = $ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $

p'(x) = $ 3ax^2+bx+c $

p''(x) = $ 6ax+2b $

p'''(x) = $ 6a $

p''''(x) = $ 0 $

Comment: Yes that will work as you would have shown that $D^{4}(p(x))=0$ for all $p(x) \in V$.